# Row click - make checkbox selected in a modal grid issue on Magento 2.4.2

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.4.2, product-grid, modal

I have a modal, listing a product grid. Same as it is for `related products` when you add a product.
My problem is that beside that I have the pointer cursor, when I click on a row the checkbox from my first column is not checked!
Please see the image below for more details:
[image]

This is the code from the ui component:

```
<columns name="associate_columns" >
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">associate_product_tab_product_listing.associate_product_tab_product_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">selectGroup</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
 .....
```

However I got this js error message, from the console:
`Uncaught TypeError: component[method] is undefined` from `static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry.js:58`. This is the method from line `58`:

```
function async(name, registry, method) {
    var args = _.toArray(arguments).slice(3);

    if (_.isString(method)) {
        registry.get(name, function (component) {
            component[method].apply(component, args); //LINE 58
        });
    } else if (_.isFunction(method)) {
        registry.get(name, method);
    } else if (!args.length) {
        return registry.get(name);
    }
}
```

The interesting part is that this works on Magento 2.3.5, but not on Magento 2.4.2-p1 .
Any clue why ? What did they change ?

Thanks